# Https not forwarding to my local server. router instead

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I start my local server and connect to my ISP's router. When I get public ip, it turn out router ip address. I set forwarding port 80 to my local server and bind with my domain name.

The problem is. When I use Http it forwarding to my local server destination which is fine but when I use Https it isn't forwarding to my local server but go to router instead and the router ip is login page for login to router setting

What settings do I need to make to set both HTTP and HTTPS forwarding to my local server?

Thank you for helping

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTTPS you normally need to forward port 443 (unless you use a custom port). But if your router listen to this already, you may also need to update the configuration in your router to not answer 443 by itself, but forward to your server.

**UPDATE**

Also, be careful if you disable https for your router, to not lose access to it and need a reset! Probably you can set it such that external access to 443 is forwarded to your server, but access from your LAN goes to the router configuration - but what is possible depends on the exact model of your router, so difficult to give precise advise there.

Comment: Thank you @gepa, It works! and Thank you for additional security advice. You save my project. I can't approve this answer, because I'm a new user maybe. If you don't mind, can you approve this post please.